# How to get current node's actual element in fancytree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fancytree

I need a get current active node's actual element in fancytree.

because I get actual element position's offset.

I searched fancytree api but i didn't get how to active node's actual element.

Could you help me?

```
  var activeNode = $('#myTree').fancytree('getActiveNode');

  //TODO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure what you mean be *actual element*, but the `<span>` element is stored as `node.span`